# Is there a way to measure the performance of an Angular microfront?

Tags: angular, performance, lighthouse, micro-frontend

Hello everyone and sorry for my bad English.

I have a question and as the title says, I wanted to know if there is a way to measure the performance of a microfrontend (Custom elements + Shell) that each microfront is expressed in an Angular module (own routes, components, pipes, flows , etc...) and with these results (metrics), determine if the code or its performance can be improved.

[image: Lighthouse]

I have been looking for tools such as Google's lighthouse, but the truth is that it does not help me much since, although it is true, it measures performance such as First Contentful Painting or SEO, but it is of the entire application and that is not what is sought anymore I want it to be by modules, why? What happens is that we have various teams developing microfronts individually, so we want to measure individual performance with some tool to determine if we are doing well with respect to performance, any help? I have searched and tried in many ways but I can't find any solution, thanks in advance.